# How can I access/manipulate data from a Stream inside a Bloc in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, stream, bloc

After calling a method in my Bloc that returns a Stream<List> from Firebase, I need to perform some logic on the data that comes from the stream (e.g. filter the data based on the userId). The problem I run into is that I can't use async/await on the stream because it throws an error saying "Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'. " Are there any strategies/patterns for accessing a stream's data inside a Bloc or does all the data manipulation need to be done in the widget with a StreamBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Use [asyncMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) for asynchronous mapping.

> Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event.